# How To Install The id3_get_tag for PHP on a Linux system

Tags: php, linux

I've done allot of searching for how to use and install the function id3_get_tag for PHP, but there was no luck. I know there is allot of Questions already asked but I could not find what I was looking for. Or even if this is the right tool for the job. I'm trying to loop through a full album and then create a HTML table of there for a web-site I am building.

Any Help Will Be Gratefully Received.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the installation guide?

-> http://php.net/manual/de/id3.installation.php

-> http://php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.php